# R packages installation

Tags: r

Do I need to install R packages in Rstudio and use the library function any time I want to work on a new script?
Or If I have installed the R packages and specifically the tidyverse for once, do I need to install tidy verse anytime I want to work on a script that requires using tidyverse?

Just learning R newly

Comment: If you have installed the package, then you just need to run `library(your_package)` each time you launch a R session

Comment: Install once, load (e.g. `library(tidyverse)`) in each new session you want to use a non-base package.